# JSPsych - Balanced allocation of participants to conditions

Tags: javascript, jspsych

I started using JSPsych/javascript a few months ago and have now coded my first full experiment. I ran a pilot and it became clear that my participants were not being evenly assigned to conditions.

To assign participants to conditions I'm using a randomisation function:

```
 jsPsych.randomization.shuffle
```

I have a 20 cell design it's quite important that allocation is approximately balanced.

I know Josh de Leeuw has some [PHP / JS functions which communicate with a MySQL database](https://github.com/vassar-cogscilab/php-mysql-save-data) which allows you to assign participants to conditions in a balanced way.

This seems a little complicated and I'm not sure I quite follow how to do it.

Has anyone found a way of assigning participants to conditions in a balanced way?

Answer (score 2):

You're right that the method that jsPsych suggests is not straightforward. One option you have is to use [JATOS](http://www.jatos.org) on your server side (it's an open-source package to manage your server).

There's an [example study](http://www.jatos.org/Example-Studies.html) (see 'Randomize tasks between workers') to do the counterbalancing exactly as you described.

You have the option of using a MySQL database or an H2 database (easier, and equally reliable as far as I can tell). You'll need to change a handful of lines in your jsPsych script to send data to JATOS but that's all described in the [docs](http://www.jatos.org/jsPsych-and-JATOS.html).

Disclaimer: I'm involved in the JATOS project. But it's open source :)

Comment: Thank you - I'll try the method you have suggested!

Comment: Having some problems with installing JATOS on my computer. Will post on the google group but the problem arises when I'm asked to log in.